# Insert into table - discard duplicates where key can be null

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a program which a user can create and edit **tasks**. Each task can have 0-n **questions** assigned to it.

When the user is editing a task, they are presented with a list of questions (previously created), which they can either (1) delete or (2) edit. They can also (3) add a new question to the list of questions.

Each question must have a relation to each assigned member, so that their progress can be tracked. This is done in `task_data_table`.

```
task_data_table
============================================================================
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
============================================================================
| id                | int(11)      | no   | PRI |  Null   | auto_increment |
| completion_date   | timestamp    | yes  |     |         |                |
| answer            | varchar(255) | yes  |     |         |                |
| task_id           | int(11)      | yes  | MUL |         |                |
| question_id       | int(11)      | yes  | MUL |         |                |
| member_id         | int(11)      | yes  | MUL |         |                |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The contents of the table might look like this:

```
=========================================================================
| id | completion_date     | answer | task_id | question_id | member_id |
=========================================================================
| 1  | 2016-05-13 11:00:00 | NULL   | 20      | NULL        | 2         |
| 2  | 2016-05-13 11:00:00 | yes    | 20      | 8           | 2         |
| 3  | 2016-05-13 11:00:00 | no     | 20      | 9           | 2         |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The first entry above has `question_id` equal to `NULL` because it is used for the task as a whole, whereas the others for a specific question. Also, each question is unique to a task.

---

I'm trying to optimize some back-end logic and query times by reducing the amount of loops and unnecessary checks done against the database when submitting the changes. One way I tried doing this was by giving `task_id` in combination with `question_id` a `UNIQUE` key so that I don't have to make checks against the database if the `task_data` for said member and question already exists before executing the `INSERT INTO`. So I did:

```
ALTER TABLE task_data_table ADD UNIQUE unique_index (question_id, student_member_id);
```

However, I just found out from the docs:

> a UNIQUE index permits multiple NULL values for columns that can contain NULL

I've looked into ways to solve this, but I've only found suggestions of using `0` as the default value, instead of `NULL`. Unfortunately, this isn't possible because both `task_id` and `question_id` are foreign keys.

I did try some queries I found with `IF NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN`, but they didn't work. How would I go about solving this issue?

Comment: In MySQL, I think this functionality requires a trigger.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, hmm... can you explain how this trigger would work/do?

Answer (score 1):

Other databases have better mechanisms for this.  In MySQL, the best solution is probably to add a fake row to `questions`.

This row should have an id of 0 or -1.  Then you can use a foreign key constraint and unique constraint to get the behavior you want.

You do need to be careful, if you are depending on the `NULL` value in the column.  One way around this is using a view:

```
create view v_task_data_table as
    select . . .,
           (case when question_id = -1 then NULL else question_id end) as question_id
    from task_data_table;
```

Then, any code that wants the `NULL` value would have it by using the view.

Comment: This is really unfortunate. Having a fake row did cross my mind, but it really seems like a potentially risky approach. Anti-pattern for sure. Back to the drawing board I guess.

Comment: @Chris . . . Other databases support filtered indexes and computed columns, which can also help implement this idea.  Actually, MySQL supports computed columns in the most recent versions, so there might be solutions in the latest version.